# Why does my RigidBody jump weirdly in the begining of the animation?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

As soon as the animation starts the top of the box weirdly jumps or wiggles, depending on wheter Mesh or Convex is selected. [Here is the download of my project](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tqg0rXLNae18c98FBXVRkFBccRNY4tRe?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen *Shape > Convex*, it makes the lid collides with the box, so instead choose *Mesh* which will respect the mesh shape. Also choose the minimum *Sensitivity > Margin*:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, now it works just fine. Could you maybe also tell me wheter i got the following right: Convex Hull doesn't have the inset, where Mesh has and that's why Convex makes it pop up. Also the margin propertie makes colliders bigger than the objects they are connected to.

Comment: convex hull creates a kind of virtual cage that contains the object, but that cage is convexe whereas your lid object is concave, so you need to switch to mesh. As for the margin it makes the object bigger, yes